# jRebel breaks loading of Application and Session Scoped beans

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty, jrebel

While starting without jRebel the debug log of jetty contains lots of messages referring MyApplicationScopedBean like:

```
13:46:29.620 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - loaded class MyApplicationScopedBean  from WebAppClassLoader=571787213@2214c7cd
13:46:32.132 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - loaded class MyApplicationScopedBean$1 from WebAppClassLoader=571787213@2214c7cd
13:46:32.162 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - loaded class MyApplicationScopedBean$2 from WebAppClassLoader=571787213@2214c7cd
...
```

But with jRebel the log contains only one string about MyApplicationScopedBean:

```
13:44:12.351 [main] DEBUG o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader - loaded class MyApplicationScopedBean from WebAppClassLoader=1298169768@4d607fa8
```

Any ideas why it could happen?

Here are maven plugins:

```
  <plugins>         
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <sessionHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
                        <sessionManager
                            implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager">
                            <!-- Disable url sessions using JSessionID -->
                            <sessionIdPathParameterName>none</sessionIdPathParameterName>
                        </sessionManager>
                    </sessionHandler>
                </webAppConfig>
                <!-- <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
                        <value>./src/etc/logback.xml</value>
                    </systemProperty>

                </systemProperties>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
            <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using jRebel 5.0 without eclipse plugin. Installation of up to date jRebel 5.1 eclipse plugin solved the problem.

UPDATE: After I upgraded my trial license to social one it stopped loading JSF beans again. Also I got annoyed by their suspicious marketing solutions:
1. Foolish misleading statements in every topic on coderanch like: "here it is: jRebel... " .
2. Social license supposes permission to post to your FB (or Twitter).
It looks like guys are really concentrated on making money at any price.

So, I decided to get rid of this bullshit and installed DCEVM. It just works! And it's free and open source.

http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/

Comment: "Upgrading" the license to social should not have any effect as the license types do not impose any restrictions on the features. So it must have been something else that affected JSF beans loading.

Comment: BTW, if it was all about money, hardly the social license ever existed since it is free. Here's the deal - you get the license and give something in return. Not like it - you're free not to use it (as you did).

Comment: @AntonArhipov, thank you for the explanation in your first comment. All I said is just IMHO yet based on some facts. You are free to promote your product, but the reasoning in your second comment is too self-contradictory to argue with it.